# Ubuntu Laptop Mouse track only works when system is plugged in

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, hardware-failure

I don't know what happened. I just wanted to use my system and discovered that the mouse track wasn't working. Then when I plugged my charger, it was working again. But when I remove the charger, it will work for some seconds then stop

Answer (score 0):

Add the mouse ID to the blacklist in laptop-mode `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf`.
First `lsusb`.
eg,

`Bus 003 Device 004: ID 09da:9090 A4 Tech Co., Ltd XL-750BK Laser Mouse`,

copy `09da:9090` and create string

`AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST=«09da:9090»`

in file `usb-autosuspend.conf`

or just turn off the hibernation of usb devices. `control_auto_autosuspend=0`